# Adding columns and its values to a list in Pandas based on a filter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as follows:

```
    In  DT_INI  DT_FIM  Status  Description
0   IN100   01/01/2022  01/02/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_01
1   IN200   01/02/2022  01/03/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_01
2   IN300   01/03/2022  01/04/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_02
3   IN400   01/04/2022  01/05/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_03
4   IN500   01/05/2022  01/06/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_03
```

I'm trying to create a very simple program which based on a list of values, which will be `jobName`, in this case `XX_01`  and `XX_02`.
This program will search in the `Description` field  and create a new list containing only the values founded in the list passed and also create\add a new column with the `jobName`.

I was able to create the filtered list:

```
list_dados = []
for i in jobName:
    list_dados.append(dados_df_2.loc[dados_df_2['Description'].str.contains(i)])

pd.concat(list_dados)
```

But, I couldnt create\add the new column jobName, tried a few thing and none worked.

the output Im looking for is as follows:

```
    In  jobName DT_INI  DT_FIM  Status  Description
0   IN100   XX_01   01/01/2022  01/02/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_01
1   IN200   XX_01   01/02/2022  01/03/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_01
2   IN300   XX_02   01/03/2022  01/04/2022  Encerrado   Abend no job XX_02
```

could you guys help me?

Comment: df.loc[df['DT_FIM']<"01-04-2022"]? If it is on datetime

Comment: but, the date columns are not important for the filter, only the list given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `.str.extract`

```py
jobName = ['XX_01', 'XX_02']

df['jobName'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'\b(' + '|'.join(jobName) + r'\b)')
```

```
print(df)

      In      DT_INI      DT_FIM     Status         Description jobName
0  IN100  01/01/2022  01/02/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_01   XX_01
1  IN200  01/02/2022  01/03/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_01   XX_01
2  IN300  01/03/2022  01/04/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_02   XX_02
3  IN400  01/04/2022  01/05/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_03     NaN
4  IN500  01/05/2022  01/06/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_03     NaN
```

To also filtered by `jobName`, you can try `dropna` by the extracted `jobName` column

```py
out = (df.assign(jobName=df['Description'].str.extract(r'(' + '|'.join(jobName) + r')'))
       .dropna(subset='jobName'))
```

```
print(out)

      In      DT_INI      DT_FIM     Status         Description jobName
0  IN100  01/01/2022  01/02/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_01   XX_01
1  IN200  01/02/2022  01/03/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_01   XX_01
2  IN300  01/03/2022  01/04/2022  Encerrado  Abend no job XX_02   XX_02
```

Comment: but here, it's not filtering only the values from the jobName list isnt? the idea is to have only the values that the jobName values are in the description.
the output should be only 3 rows(without the indexes 3 and 4 because they aren't in the jobName list. Do you think I can use this in my loop?